# Surface area of a sphere segment.

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-trigonometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I got this problem and solution in a paper but cannot find how they have solved it. Consider I have a sphere that is equally divided into two different patch(P, S). The sphere can rotate and translate(up-down) at the air-water interface. The angle $\alpha$ defines the position of the sphere (alpha increase means the sphere goes towards the air). The angle $\beta$ defines the rotation of the sphere. So the surface area of any patch into any phase changes with the position and orientation(example: area of P inside air phase will change with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ angle). Now the calculation of the surface area of P part of the sphere in air is given by this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZxI6.jpg). I understand the limit for $\theta$ direction but did not find out how the limit comes for $φ$ direction.
Here is the visual representation of the problem

[image]

Please keep in mind that the figure is only $2D$ presentation of a $3D$ sphere where the coordinate system refers as $(r, θ, φ)$ .

Comment: @Anirban Niloy Thanks for editing. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: I'm only in 10th grade!!!! No idea about spherical geometry, only know its some formula. Wait untill somebody gives a satisfactory and meaningful answer. Hopefully, you will get that.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy ohh i got it.